# issues with graphics.py slowing program

Tags: python, graphics

The code below is my code for making 2 "computers" play tiktaktoe against eachother,
it all worked perfect, untill I started making the graphics for it using `graphics.py`,
now after a few turns it starts slowing down a lot.
is there anything I'm doing wrong?

also, since I'm new to programming I'm wondering if there is a better solution for all the if statements running back to back

```
#               tiktaktoe
#
#the numbers of each position
#            1  |   2   |   3
#               |       |
#        ----------------------
#            4  |   5   |   6
#               |       |
#        ----------------------
#            7  |   8   |    9
#               |       |

#import modules

from random import randrange
from graphics import *
import time
import os

#base variables
win = GraphWin("tiktaktoe",500,500)
x = {1:120,2:240,3:350,4:120,5:240,6:350,7:120,8:240,9:350}
y = {1:120,2:120,3:120,4:240,5:240,6:240,7:350,8:350,9:350}
unfilled = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
p1 = []
p2 = []
turn = 1

#setup playscreen
pt = Line(Point(175,75),Point(175,375))
pt.draw(win)
pt = Line(Point(300,75),Point(300,375))
pt.draw(win)
pt = Line(Point(75,175),Point(375,175))
pt.draw(win)
pt = Line(Point(75,300),Point(375,300))
pt.draw(win)


#randomized moves
while unfilled: 
    time.sleep(1)
#check for turn
    if turn == 1:
#select random number
        move = randrange(1,10)
#check if random number already is used
        if move in unfilled:
#registrate the move and show the output
            unfilled.remove(move)
            p1.append(move)
            turn = 2
            print(move)
            print(x[move])
            print(y[move])
            cir = Circle(Point(x[move],y[move]),25)
            cir.setOutline('blue')
            cir.setFill('blue')
            cir.draw(win)
            #checking if there are 3 dots in a row
            if 1 in p1 and 2 in p1 and 3 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 4 in p1 and 5 in p1 and 6 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 7 in p1 and 8 in p1 and 9 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 1 in p1 and 4 in p1 and 7 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 2 in p1 and 5 in p1 and 8 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 3 in p1 and 6 in p1 and 9 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 3 in p1 and 5 in p1 and 7 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 1 in p1 and 5 in p1 and 9 in p1:
                print ("p1 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()

    elif turn == 2:
        move = randrange(1,10)
        if move in unfilled:
            unfilled.remove(move)
            p2.append(move)
            turn = 1
            print(move)
            print(x[move])
            print(y[move])
            cir = Circle(Point(x[move],y[move]),25)
            cir.setOutline('red')
            cir.setFill('red')
            cir.draw(win)
            if 1 in p2 and 2 in p2 and 3 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 4 in p2 and 5 in p2 and 6 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 7 in p2 and 8 in p2 and 9 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 1 in p2 and 4 in p2 and 7 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 2 in p2 and 5 in p2 and 8 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 3 in p2 and 6 in p2 and 9 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 3 in p2 and 5 in p2 and 7 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
            if 1 in p2 and 5 in p2 and 9 in p2:
                print ("p2 won")
                time.sleep(10)
                exit()
```

Comment: Not sure what happens, but this library was not meant to be used for more than a demo. You should replace it by something that is actually usable, like "tkinter" from the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: @JulienD Thank you for your response. tkinter did not solve the problem, but im glad i learned about this. i found the problem, and it was a misplased `sleep()` function.